# What statistical tests or procedures should I conduct for analyzing a repeated measures design experiment?

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, psychology, levenes-test

I have conducted a repeated measures design experiment on Paivio 1971's dual coding experiment, but my two conditions are Dual-Coding (visual + auditory) and Auditory on Animal Sounds. There are two experimental groups: Group A & Group B. Group B is the counterbalanced version of Group A to reduce order effects. The sampling was random sampling, and there are 10 participants in each experimental group.

I have obtained the mean and the standard deviation population of each condition, so mean and median for Group A Auditory and Dual-Coding, then Group B Dual-Coding and Auditory.

I have also downloaded SPSS and obtained the IQR, but upon further research, it is only useful if there is some sort of outlier (Which I checked in SPSS, and the box-plot showed no circle or asterisk), so is this good to include as a resistant measure?

For the inferential part of my experiment, what tests should I run? I ran a t-test and from that did a normality test using One-Sample Kolmogorov and Smirnov test. I also ran a One-way ANOVA test for Levene's test of homogeneity of variances.

I'm a high school student, so I am very doubtful if I am going correctly.

I wondered if someone could give me a list of statistical tests or measurements that I should conduct for the Descriptive part and the Inferential part of my analytical work.

Thanks